# Samsung Intent For OnActivityResult coming Null when call camera

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, onactivityresult

I am using following code to get picture from camera. Except samsung it is working fine in other mobiles. please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
 final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temp" + File.separator);
        root.mkdir();
        final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam){
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        //FileSystem
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Image Source");
        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

And onActivityResult

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
             if(data!=null){
                Logv("Data","got some data");
              }
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Except samsung it is working fine in other mobiles

No, it is only working with the camera apps on the devices that you have tried. It generally will not work for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

> please let me know what i am doing wrong

You are assuming that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is supposed to return a result `Intent`. [It is not required when you provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). You know where you asked for the image to be saved (the value you supplied to `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, so go look there for the image.

Note that there are some buggy camera apps that will ignore `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (storing the image where they want), so if the image from your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request is not in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you are out of luck.